# Using multiple clauses in a IF statement comparing regular expressions

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I'm writing a bash program which performs various tasks. I have an IF statement which may be causing a problem. Is the following scripting correct?

```
if [[ ! $description =~ "Design" ]] || [[ ! $description =~ "Digital" ]]; then

        echo 'Does not match Design or Digital'
else
        echo 'A match has been found'
fi
```

Comment: you should use double quotes for your  `echo`es, the quote in *Doesn't* closes the string and you get an unexpected EOF error

Comment: It's syntactically correct I think - but you may want to review [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) regarding the logic

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. As you mentioned steeldriver it is syntactically correct, but I made a modification to the operator in the clause.

```
#/bin/bash

description="Advert"

if [[ $description =~ "Design" ]] || [[ $description =~ "Digital" ]]; then

    echo 'Matches Design or Digital'
else
    echo 'Does not match'
fi
```

Thanks for the advice everyone!

Answer (score 0):

For the outputted message to be correct in the original, the first echo should have said `Does not match Design *and* Digital`. A match would have been found on the string `Digital Design`, for example.

---

When using the regular expression operator `=~` in `bash`, the left hand side should be a quoted string and the right hand side should generally be left unquoted:

```
#/bin/bash

description='Advert'

if [[ "$description" =~ Design  ]] ||
   [[ "$description" =~ Digital ]]; then
    echo 'Matches Design or Digital'
else
    echo 'Does not match'
fi
```

This does not matter in *this* case, but it does in the following:

```
description='Advert'

if [[ "$description" =~ "Ad.*" ]]; then
    echo 'Matches "Ad.*"'
else
    echo 'Does not match'
fi
```

This will print `Does not match`.